# What exactly does Ubuntu Power Mode option "Power Saver" do?

Tags: gnome, power-management, performance, gnome-power-manager

I am experiencing issues with [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate) when Ubuntu's Power Mode is set to "Power Saver"  and I want to understand what exactly does this option "Power Saver" do to the system. Looking around I could not find any detailed documentation.

Obviously, since we're at it, it would be useful to also understand what do the other to options do - "Balanced" and "Performance".

Comment: One thing dropping from Performance to Balanced that happens is the default GPU is switched from the dedicated GPU to the integrated.

Comment: ubfan1 thanks for the comment. I would like to avoid shouting out individual items, and instead I'm looking for comprehensive documentation which lists *all* thins that are impacted by setting power profile to "Power Saver".